# Word for arrangement when things are placed according to their sizes?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word for arrangement in which things are placed according to their sizes. Like the biggest, smaller than biggest, ....., smallest. The arrangement fashion could be horizontal or vertical (stacked onto each other).

Comment: Do you mean *graduated*, like these [graduated cylinders?](https://www.scientificsonline.com/product/graduated-cylinder-measuring-set)

Comment: @JLG I found a more relevant word i.e 'nesting' or 'nest'. Thanks for your help, btw.

Comment: Typically you’d just say they are [ordered/sorted] by size. And if necessary, “biggest to smallest/smallest on top/biggest first, etc” whichever is applicable.

Comment: @KhanI'd have said things were 'nested' when the smaller ones were *inside* the larger ones, rather than stacked or next to each other.

Comment: From largest to smallest or from smallest to largest.  Objects are placed on the shelf from largest to smallest. AKA: descending order by size or ascending order by size. There are rarely single words for these things. I see so many questions about that. The answers, as here, are usually phrases, not words.

Comment: @Khan I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Spagirl Sorry for a confusing comment I posted earlier. What I meant actually was that my product set (with 3 variants) for which I needed the word can be nested into each other. So the term 'nest' somehow fits in my case. Another term, ordinal, as suggested in an answer below is not very common so I am not considering it.

Comment: @Khan If nesting is also true for you product, use the term. I just want to be clear for others reading the Q in future that 'nesting' doesn't mean 'arranging in size order'.

Comment: I arrange things **sizewise** myself. That could *easily* be colloquial. It shows up in some, but not nearly all dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a single word, but when I was a child in school, and we were supposed to get in line for something (going to lunch, a fire drill, etc.), the teacher would often tell us to line up **in size order**.

[Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20size%20order&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20size%20order%3B%2Cc0) shows that this phrase has been steadily increasing in usage over the past 60 years.